# Отображение файла в памяти

Tags: c#, память, memory

Как прочесть записанный файл и дозаписать в файл? в файл записывается последняя нажатая кнопка, а не дозапись. С OpenExisting выводит на экран, а с CreateFromFile ничего.

Есть 2 процесса, один по нажатию на которые в файл записывается строка «Была нажата n-ая кнопка»,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateOrOpenMappedFile();
            textBox1.Text = "the first button was pressed";
        }
protected void CreateOrOpenMappedFile()
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryMappedFile oMemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("YourMemoryMappedFileName", 10000);
            bool IsmutexCreated;

            Mutex oMutex = new Mutex(true, "NonPersisterMemoryMappedFilemutex", out IsmutexCreated);

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(oMemoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream());
            sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            sw.Close();
            oMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             string sMessage = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

а в родительском процессе выводится содержание файла.

```
protected void ReadMemoryMappedFille()
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryMappedFile oMemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"SPO4.dta", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, "YourMemoryMappedFileName", 10000);

            Mutex oMutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("NonPersisterMemoryMappedFilemutex");
            oMutex.WaitOne();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(oMemoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream());

            richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
            oMutex.ReleaseMutex();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             string sMessage = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Comment: А зачем вам MemoryMappedFile? Чем обыкновенный доступ к файлу не угодил?

Comment: @VladD Через обыкновенный доступ к файлу я уже работал через File.CreateText(path) и File.AppendText(path).

Comment: [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5h0z48dh(v=vs.110).aspx) умеет открывать файлы для совместного использования. Просто открываете с правом Read для всех посторонних и спокойно пишете в одном процессе, и периодически дочитываете данные в другом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел при объявлении `MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"SPO4.dta", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, "YourMemoryMappedFileName", 10000);` в Form_load, а дозапись шла через `MemoryMappedFile oMemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("YourMemoryMappedFileName", 10000);`